# Python window vs Toolbox script in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arctoolbox, python-window

My question is similar to [Adding Layer in current session using ARCPY](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/adding-layer-in-current-session-using-arcpy) . My script works in ArcMap python window but not as a script in toolbox.  I am running ArcGIS 10.0 SP4. The script is given below, and the error says it fails at line 3, "CreateObject cannot open map document"

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as map
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SectionClip",df)[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(updateLayer,"SectionInner2")
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"SectionInner",df)[0]
newupdateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SectionInner2",df)[0]
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(newupdateLayer,sourceLayer)
newupdateLayer.showLabels = True
for lyr in map.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == "SectionInner2":
        lyr.showLabels = True
        for lblclass in lyr.labelClasses:
            lblclass.expression = '"%s" & [SECTION] & "%s"' % ("<CLR red='0' green='0' blue='0'>""<FNT size='12'>""<BOL>", "</BOL>""</FNT>""</CLR>")
            lblclass.showClassLabels = True

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
```

I am unable to upgrade to ArcGIS 10.1 any time soon so the option of using a python add-in is not available.

Comment: Do you have the "Always run in foreground" and "Run Python script in process" options checked?

Comment: I think the reason @blah238 asks his question is described well in the online help under the heading [Reference a map document on disk or use the CURRENT keyword within ArcMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006s000000)

Comment: Did @blah238 suggestion help you?  If so, then let us know so that can be transferred to an Answer that you can Accept.

Comment: Checked both "Always run in foreground" and "Run Python script in process". Still not working. btw thanks PolyGeo for the link, helped me understand what the checks were for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing I see in your code that could cause this problem is that you are setting the MXD value to "CURRENT", which is fine... IF you have an MXD open (executing the script tool from within ArcMap).

I was able to cause your code to fail with the same response if I tried executing the code form the stand-alone ArcCatalog application. Is that what you were doing?

Screenshot using ArcCatalog to execute a Script Tool
[image]

If trying to run the script from stand-alone ArcCatalog was your problem, you have two options to run your script.

 1. Run the Script Tool from the Catalog tab within the ArcMap
[image]

 2. Application Set the MXD parameter as a path to a valid MXD

`arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"c:\path\to\your\map.mxd")`

You can read more details about the use of the arcpy.Mapping.MapDocument class [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/MapDocument/00s30000000n000000/)