# foreground arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") in python script in single ArcMap produces createobject errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I'm running ArcGIS 10.3.1. and desire to list layers in the current mxd. I'm using the "CURRENT" method...

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

...within a python script tool, accessed via a single ArcMap session with the environment setting set to foreground processing. The usage is correct (identical to the help) and has worked for me last year. **why would a foreground process fail to find the single mxd that it's being run from?**

[Link Esri ArcGIS 10.3 Help: Map Documents](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm)

[image]

```
    import arcpy
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        arcpy.AddMessage(lyr.name)
    del mxd
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ... current mxd ")
```

[image]

Comment: I think I know what is going on here but I think it will be much clearer if you can replace the picture of code with code as text that has been formatted using the **`{}`** button.  However, can you also remove the `try/except` block from any code presented here because that masks the errors that Python provides to help you and us debug.

Comment: Having the error message as text will be helpful to future searches like this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=createobject+%5Barcpy%5D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking of an [earlier Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159967/115), I was going to say that the Python script tool is running in a separate process from ArcMap, but when I tested your code in ArcMap at ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop it ran without a problem.

I think you should try closing ArcMap, and perhaps even rebooting, and then re-opening ArcMap to run your test again.  This would eliminate the possibility that another process is somehow conflicting with yours.

Also, double-check that you have Run Python script in process checked.  When I ran it as below I got an error, but it was different to yours.

[image]

> Executing: test2 Start Time: Thu Mar 31 18:31:37 2016 Running script
>   test2... ERROR 000714: Error in script test2. Error in executing:
>   cmd.exe /C C:\Temp\test.py  "#"
>
> Failed to execute (test2). Failed at Thu Mar 31 18:31:48 2016 (Elapsed
>   Time: 10.77 seconds)

---

Alternatively, as you have commented, and done successfully:

> run a repair and remove your templates

i.e.

> Problem solved: I deleted the normal template [(Normal.mxt)], created a new mxd, and
>   the script worked as designed.

Comment: I had thought the same and had rebooted and repaired my ArcGIS Install. Bit it still had issues.  I tested the "Run Python script in process" in both states, it was not fruitful in any case. I'll get a co worker to test it as well.

Comment: @GISI Is there any chance that you may be trying to run this tool from ArcCatalog (to save the overhead of ArcMap)?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39119/python-console-vs-toolbox-script-in-arcgis

Comment: Nope. No chance at all, it's always run via ArcMap.

Comment: I've had a coworker run this and they did not have problems. Therefore it's a problem with my ArcGIS Desktop Install. Despite running repairs, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @GISI I wonder whether you are inadvertently running a different Python setup than what you think.  I try to avoid playing around with PYTHONPATH etc but if you do a full uninstall of ArcGIS for Desktop, and remove any Python remnants, then reinstalling ArcGIS for Desktop with its Python may just fix it.

Comment: @GISI perhaps use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output to see what Python your "broken" install and your colleague's working install are using.

Comment: Problem solved: I deleted the normal template, created a new mxd, and the script worked as designed. If you edit you answer to include: run a repair and remove your templates I will accept it.

Comment: @GISI All's well that end's well.  I should have remembered to suggest deleting your Normal.mxt.